# Dynamic tabs using Bootstrap not working! Doesn´t open on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

my problem is simple. I created some dynamic tabs with content but they doesn't open... I have tried everything. I think something is wrong with the jquery:

```
$(".nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
})
```

But I'm not sure. I will appreciate any kind of help, thank you very much!!

This is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/j6kLbgz1/

If you need something else tell me!

Comment: Works fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/j6kLbgz1/2/)**, you need to add reference to `twitter-bootstrap` - `css` and `js` files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about tab in jsfiddle, the only problem is because you did't include bootstrap library. Place the below link at `External Resources` section..

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

See Update [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/cu9mp1cL/)

Comment: Oh! Well, that was the first time I used that function... Thank you very much sir!! Just one more question...

To add that js script to my bootstrap folder should I just add it to the bootstrap.min.js file?

Comment: There are two options, you can include inside your web page by using above link or directly download the libraries(js and css) and place it into your bootstrap folder then referenced it using `<script>` and `<link>`  for `js` and `css` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

JS reference is missing. Hence the jquery isn't responding.

Click on External Resources on the left hand menu and add thee above reference.